# WSO2 IS v. 5.3.0 New Tenant can't be created

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have installed new version of WSO2 Identity Server v.5.3.0.
When I try to create new tenant I get exceptions:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-19 16:54:17,102] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.util.ClaimsMgtUtil} -  Unable to retrieve the claim for the given tenant 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Mapped attribute cannot be found for claim : http://wso2.org/claims/lastname in user store : PRIMARY
```

and

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-19 16:54:17,102] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.util.ClaimsMgtUtil} -  Unable to retrieve the claim for the given tenant 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Mapped attribute cannot be found for claim : http://wso2.org/claims/lastname in user store : PRIMARY
```

These claims exist in DB. There is new structure in DB of claim tables.
In version 5.2 there weren't any problems in this part.

I suppose that new user (admin of tenant) can't be created. 
A simple other user through "Add User" can be created  properly.

We have different data sources for user management ant identities (WSO2_UM and WSO2_AM). New claims structure is in WSO2_AM. Maybe this is the reason of problems?

This problem is very, very important for us.
Maybe we have come back to version 5.2?

Comment: I discovered that new record for claim dialect for new tenant is created (in table IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT) but there are no claim records for new tenant in table IDN_CLAIM - no claims are copied from super tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. I'm very sorry for my mistakes. 
There was one mistake in configuration files.